# How to change name of xaml attribute in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to serialize objects of class to xaml format. However, all of the properties name of class are directly serialized and I can't change their name.

I've used the

```
[DataMember(Name = "NameToChange")]`
```

attribute, but this still not solve the problem. 
Please help me on this.

Here is the class:

```
public partial class XObject
{
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public string AtName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Name = value;
        }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public string AtType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.m_TypeToken;
        }
        set
        {
            this.m_TypeToken = value;
        }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public string AtSerialize
    {
        get
        {
            return this.m_SerializeToken;
        }
        set
        {
            this.m_SerializeToken = value;
        }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public List<string> AtValue
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Values;
        }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Dictionary<string, XObject> AtAttached
    {
        get
        {
            return m_AttachedAttributes;
        }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public string AtDynamic
    {
        get
        {
            return m_DynamicValue;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateToken()
    {
        AtSerialize = (true == HasAttribute(AttributeNameToken_Serialize)) ? GetAttribute(AttributeNameToken_Serialize) : null;
        AtType = (true == HasAttribute(AttributeNameToken_Type)) ? GetAttribute(AttributeNameToken_Type) : null;

        foreach (XObject member in this)
        {
            member.UpdateToken();
        }
    }

    private string m_TypeToken = null;
    private string m_SerializeToken = null;

}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the class you want to serialize and the method you use to serialize it? I also assume you want to serialize to Xml,  not Xaml.

Comment: @RonBeyer Xaml Serialization is awesome for object graphs... unlike XML, which is easier to transfer between different projects but has a lot of limitations when it comes to complex objects. So I think the question is really about Xaml